# Getting elements of a JSON string python

Tags: python, json

Well, this is my JSON string:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"firstname lastname","longitude":"45.567856","latitude":"345.2334"},
{"id":2,"name":"firstname1 lastname1","longitude":"45.567856","latitude":"345.2334"}]
```

This is my code where I'd like to split it:

```
api = 'http://localhost:8080/serviceBackend/employees'
json_data = requests.get(api).json()
print(json_data)

employeeName =  json_data['']['name']
print(employeeName)
```

If  I  run this code I'm  getting this error `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

The  result should be

firstname lastname, firstname1 lastname1

Comment: Okay, so where you have `json_data['']['name']`, what do you expect `json_data['']` to mean? What should the result be, and why? The error message says `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`. Did you try to understand that? Do you know what a `TypeError` is? Do you know what a `list` is, and what an `index` is? Can you think of a reason why the error might be complaining about a `list index`? Do you expect `''` to be a valid `list index`?

Comment: "The result should be" Okay, so you want to repeatedly print out some information, `for` each of the items that is `in` the list that you get from the JSON? Maybe you should have something in your code that reflects that? Hint, hint.

Answer (score 1):

You can try This:

```
api = 'http://localhost:8080/serviceBackend/employees'

json_data = requests.get(api).json()

print(json_data)

employeeName =  ', '.join([data.get('name') for data in json_data])

print(employeeName)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
>>> a = [{"id":1,"name":"firstname lastname","longitude":"45.567856","latitude":"345.2334"},
... {"id":2,"name":"firstname1 lastname1","longitude":"45.567856","latitude":"345.2334"}]
>>> ', '.join([i.get('name') for i in a])
'firstname lastname, firstname1 lastname1'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

you're trying to get variables from loop statement.
you can move by loop with such code:

```
names = []
for item in json_data:
   # get name key from item in type of dictionary and put it in names list
   names.apend(item.get('name'))
```

or using list comprehension, a bit sophisticated but more 'elegant':

```
names = [item.get('name') for item in json_data]
print(names)
```

So your code looks like this:

```
api = 'http://localhost:8080/serviceBackend/employees'
json_data = requests.get(api).json()
print(json_data)
employeeName = [item.get('name') for item in json_data]
print(employeeName)
```